# Cross compile Qt to ARM using arm-linux-gnueabihf 4.8

Tags: c++, linux, qt, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack

I am trying to cross compile Qt 4.8.2 for a BeagleBone Black(Debian Wheezy ) with Ubuntu but every time the compiler throws a Segmentation fault error. What do I miss?

```
../JavaScriptCore/wtf/Vector.h: In instantiation of ‘void WTF::Vector<T, inlineCapacity>::shrink(size_t) [with T = JSC::Identifier; unsigned int inlineCapacity = 20u; size_t = unsigned int]’:
../JavaScriptCore/wtf/Vector.h:520:33:   required from ‘WTF::Vector<T, inlineCapacity>::~Vector() [with T = JSC::Identifier; unsigned int inlineCapacity = 20u]’
../JavaScriptCore/runtime/PropertyNameArray.h:46:9:   required from here
../JavaScriptCore/wtf/Vector.h:860:54: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
     TypeOperations::destruct(begin() + size, end());
```

Configured with:

```
./configure -v -opensource -confirm-license -xplatform linux-arm-gnueabihf-g++ -embedded arm -little-endian -host-little-endian -prefix /usr/local/qt4.8.2-arf -nomake demos -nomake examples -no-qt3support -qt-gfx-linuxfb -qt-gfx-qvfb -qt-gfx-vnc -no-accessibility -no-openssl
```

qmake.conf

```
MAKEFILE_GENERATOR      = UNIX
TARGET_PLATFORM         = unix
TEMPLATE                = app
CONFIG                  += qt warn_on release incremental link_prl gdb_dwarf_index
QT                      += core gui
QMAKE_INCREMENTAL_STYLE = sublib

include(../common/linux.conf)
include(../common/gcc-base-unix.conf)
include(../common/g++-unix.conf)

QMAKE_CC                = arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8
QMAKE_CXX               = arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.8
QMAKE_LINK              = arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.8
QMAKE_LINK_SHLIB        = arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.8


QMAKE_AR                = arm-linux-gnueabi-ar cqs
QMAKE_OBJCOPY           = arm-linux-gnueabi-objcopy
QMAKE_STRIP             = arm-linux-gnueabi-strip

load(qt_config)
```

configure output: http://pastebin.com/pSQJ7Rj5

make output: http://www67.zippyshare.com/v/ciLsozUA/file.html

Comment: What's your target OS on BBB? Have you looked at [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/)? It provides both Qt 4 and Qt5 as also BBB target.

Comment: Debian Wheezy. I am afraid that i won't be able to access the board if i use Buildroot, there are so many options...

Comment: Another option would be to take Debian 8 on both PC and BBB and take a look at [multiarch](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch) approach.

Comment: 1. Compile Qt 4.8.6 with Buildroot. 
2. Qt Creator to use it for cross compile. 
3. Install Qt4 on BBB(Debian 7)
It seems to work. Thank you very much